# Using .htaccess to redirect bots

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, bots, web-crawler

So my website has a page called presets_pc.html, which dynamically loads content, and I want to redirect bots to presets_pc_fallback.php, which literally dumps the database on the page.
I'm pretty new to this stuff, and can't get RewriteRule to work; can you help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691956/redirect-all-bots-using-htaccess-apache/2693694#2693694

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can tell whether a bot is accessing your site is through the `User-Agent` HTTP request header. Anyone can spoof what that is so there's no real guarantee. If you have a list of bots you want to affect, you can look up the "exclusion" user agents from a site like [robotstxt](http://www.robotstxt.org/db/googlebot.html) and chain them into a `RewriteCond` match.

For example, google, infoseek, msn:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|InfoSeek|msnbot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?presets_pc\.html$ /presets_pc_fallback.php [L,R]
```

Comment: works like a charm. i just got the regexp wrong.